# Blending text, rendered by FreeType in color and alpha

Tags: c, image-processing, language-agnostic, alpha, freetype

I am using FreeType to render some texts.

The surface where I want to draw the text is a bitmap image with format ARGB, pre-multiplied alpha.

The needed color of the text is also ARGB.

The rendered FT_Bitmap has format FT_PIXEL_MODE_LCD - it is as the text is rendered with white color on black background, with sub-pixel antialiasing.

So, for every pixel I have 3 numbers:

`Da, Dr, Dg, Db` - destination pixel ARGB (the background image).

`Fr, Fg, Fb` - FreeType rendered pixel (FT_Bitmap rendered with FT_RENDER_MODE_LCD)

`Ca, Cr, Cg, Cb` - The color of the text I want to use.

So, the question: How to properly combine these 3 numbers in order to get the result bitmap pixel.

The theoretical answers are OK and even better than code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discovery, I found the right answer. It is disappointing.

It is impossible to draw subpixel rendered graphics (including fonts) on a transparent image with RGBA format.

In order to properly render such graphics, a format that supports separate alpha channels for every color is mandatory.

For example 48 bit per pixes: RrGgBg where r, g and b are the alpha channels for the red, green and blue collor channels respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Interpet the FreeType data not as actual RGB colors (these 'raw' values are to draw text in black) but as *intensities* of the destination text color.

So the full intensity of each `F` color component is `F*C/255`. However, since your `C` also includes an alpha component, the intensity is scaled by it:

```
 s' = F*C*A/(255 * 255)
```

assuming, of course, that `F`, `C`, and `A` are inside the usual range of 0..255. `A` is a fraction `A/255`, and the second division is to bring `F*C` back into the target range. `s'` is now the *derived* source color.

On to plotting it. Per color component, the new color gets add to `D`, and `D` in turn gets dimished by the source's alpha `255-A` (scaled).

That leads to the full sum

```
D' = D*(255-A)/255 + F*C*A/(255 * 255)
```

equal to (moving one value to the right)

```
D' = (D*(255-A) + F*C*A/255)/255
```

for each separate channel r,g,b of `D`, `F`, `C` and `A`. The last one, alpha, also needs a separate calculation for each channel because your FreeType output data returns this format.

If the calculation is too slow, you could compare the visual result with not-LCD-optimized grayscale output from FreeType. I suspect that especially on 'busy' (not entirely monochrome) backgrounds the extra calculations are simply not worth it.
The numerical advantage of a pure grayscale input is that you only have to calculate `A` and `1-A` once for each triplet of RGB colors.

The "background" also has an alpha channel but to draw text "on" it you can regard this as 'unused'. Drawing a transparent item onto another transparent item does not, in general, change its intrinsic transparency.

Comment: Which alpha is A? Of the background (destination) - Da or the color - Ca?

Comment: This answer is completely wrong because it doesn't consider the sub-pixel coloring at all. One test is to render the text as black on a white background, rather than the white text on a black background as returned by FreeType.

Comment: `A` is the alpha of your text color `C`. All three other values `F`, `C`, and `D` are RGB triplets (and `D` does not need its alpha changed). For a grayscale FreeType character you can use `A' = A*F` and remove the `F` from the equations.

Comment: @MarkRansom: ouch! Doesn't FreeType return simple intensities and leave further coloring to the end user then? This per-channel calculation preserves the subpixel antialiasing, doesn't it? (But scaled per the source alpha, naturally.)

Comment: @Jongware D - the destination (background) has alpha channel and need it in order to be later blended with other images.

Comment: @johnfound: yes, and that's why I think you should not change it. Imagine a 25% background where you draw a 50% transparent text on. That operation does not change the background to be 'more' or 'less' transparent; it should only change the RGB values (by that 50%).

Comment: @Jongware the whole point of sub-pixel antialiasing is to take advantage of the layout of LCD pixels, where the red sub-pixel is closest to the pixel to the left and the blue sub-pixel is closest to the pixel to the right. (Or vice versa depending on the physical layout, but I think most modern LCD panels are laid out that way)

Comment: So @Mark, my initial gut feeling was to add a remark that "subpixel antialiasing makes no sense on an intermediate image, only when directly blitted to the screen" - because FreeType calculates it *for* a specific screen position. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jongware I'm not sure. It might be correct to interpret the R,G,B values individually as intensities on an X-axis that is 3 times wider than normal, but I haven't yet figured out how to translate those back into arbitrary foreground and background colors.

Comment: @Jongware How about drawing on 100% transparent background (0, 0, 0, 0) with pure black (1, 0, 0, 0) and later blending it on some other image?

Comment: @johnfound: there are different interpretations of what transparency on top of transparency should do. Perhaps you are looking for `max(Asrc,Adest)` (only make *dest* less transparent, never more).